# Un array es una lista secuencial?

Tags: java, java-8

Tengo entendido que hay dos tipos de listas: las enlazadas y las secuenciales. En el caso de las enlazadas en java tenemos la clase java.util.LinkedList pero en el caso de las listas secuenciales no he encontrado ningun tipo de clase. Creo que un array es un ejemplo de lista secuencial pero no lo tengo claro. Alguien podría aclararme estos conceptos?

Comment: [Aquí tienes la respuesta: **`AbstractSequentialList`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSequentialList.html). Si lees atentamente la explicación verás que dice claramente que el acceso a los `Arrays` es aleatorio (random), no secuencial.

Comment: De entrada tienes un error de concepto. Una lista enlazada es una lista secuencial.

Comment: Estamos hablando de **acceso secuencial** o de **uso de memoria en posiciones secuenciales**? A un array se le suele asignar posiciones secuenciales en memoria, pero es de acceso aleatorio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay 2 tipos de listas: las de acceso directo y las de acceso secuencial. El [acceso directo o aleatorio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceso_aleatorio) es cuando accedes a un elemento de la lista de forma directa o aleatoria. [Acceso secuencial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceso_secuencial) significa que debes acceder a los elementos de dicha lista en orden secuencial.

En el caso de Java dichas listas están implementadas en [`java.util.LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) y [`java.util.ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). `LinkedList` es una lista enlazada doble, y para acceder a sus elementos debes hacerlo secuencialmente. `ArrayList` utiliza un arreglo de tamaño fijo, y lo redimensiona cuando es necesario, y el acceso a sus elementos es directo.

Answer (score 0):

Los Arrays en Java son un conjunto secuencial de memoria a las que se accede a través de un índice de posición. La longitud de un Array en Java tiene longitud fija mientras que las Listas (List) su longitud es variable.

Las matrices en Java son objetos, por lo que cuentan con propiedades y métodos para manipularlos.

Comment: entonces según tu definición de un array sería una lista secuencial verdad?